# Disable or Ignore a Testfile in Angular2 using Karma / Jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Is there a way to disable or ignore a `xxx.spec.ts` Testing File in Typescript?
Maybe with a Comment or a Decorator?

Comment: how is your project set up?

Comment: My Project was set up with AngularCLI

Comment: can inactive a "describe" or "it" block using "xdescribe" and "xit". But that not really ignore the file.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `angular-cli` you can modify `src/test.ts`

Look for a line like this:

```
let context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

Otherwise you can use plugins like https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-jasmine-spec-tags